# How to create cone shape using clip path css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Now I try create sector shape or cone shape on css and html for write inside text.
[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSaZv.png). If someone have any idea please write. I try use `clip-path` and `shape-outside` for this. but I cannot do it, I want to this [image: like this picture]

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so far. That way we can assist you without being a free code writing service (we're not) - [Even if it is something like this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)

Comment: I want to only using html + css

Comment: [Free code searching service](https://codepen.io/spilliams/pen/AJpEvw)